# Disallow multiple regex patterns in a Joi schema property

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I want to add a Joi schema property that disallows multiple regex patterns.
I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string().invalid(
    Joi.string().pattern(/^\d+$/),
    Joi.string().pattern(/^Hello \d+$/),
  )
});
```

I also tried using the `alternatives` method:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.string().pattern(/^\d+$/),
    Joi.string().pattern(/^Hello \d+$/),
  ).not().match('all')
});
```

Here, I get the following error: `Cannot merge type string with another type: alternatives`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [invert](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#stringpatternregex-name--options---aliases-regex:%7E:text=optional%20pattern%20name.-,invert,-%2D%20optional%20boolean%20flag) option in [string.pattern()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#stringpatternregex-name--options---aliases-regex)

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-a5odfg?file=index.js)**

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string()
    .pattern(/^\d+$/, { invert: true })
    .pattern(/^Hello \d+$/, { invert: true }),
});
```